# Open Outlook incoming messages shown as Windows notification

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, notifications

I often get Windows notification at the bottom right of my screen. Is there a possibility to automatically open notifications that are for Outlook messages? Would it also be possible to automatically delete them when pressing a shortcut?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Outlook new message alert pop-up depends on Windows notification. If you'd like to turn it off, you can go to Outlook client and click File > Option to set it or turn off Windows notification for Outlook. For your reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-new-message-alert-pop-up-on-or-off-9940c70e-b306-442e-a856-d94b20318481

Comment: Thanks but I was more looking for a shortcut to open the notification